# Example of non reduced representable functor from simplicial rings

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\text{sCR}_k$ be the over category of simplicial commuative rings (so objects are maps $R \to k$), where $k$ is the simplicial field generated by a non-derived field of the same name. Let $R \in \text{sCR}_k$ and consider the functor $F_R: \text{sCR}_k \to \text{sSet}$ given by $F_R(A)=\text{Hom}(R,A)$, where $\text{Hom}$ denotes the simplicially enriched internal hom on $\text{sCR}_k$. I am reading the paper by Galatius-Venkatesh on derived deformation rings, and they claim that $F_R(k)$ is not always contractible (i.e $F$ might not be reduced) but I am having trouble finding an example of this.

More precisely they define $F_R$ as a functor from $\text{sArt}_k$- the full subcategory of $\text{sCR}_k$ consisting of simplicial Artin rings.